# WPF -> Silverlight (EventTrigger)

Tags: c#, silverlight

Всем привет. Есть следующий код, который у меня отлично работает в приложении WPF, но в приложении Silverlight ругается на то, что у EventTrigger нет свойства SourceName.

Логика следующая: при нажатии на кнопке скрываем Grid и кнопку на которую нажали, показываем другую кнопку, при нажатии на неё происходит обратное действие.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger SourceName="HyperlinkButtonCollapsed" RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CollapsedGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <Visibility>Hidden</Visibility>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HyperlinkButtonDetails" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HyperlinkButtonCollapsed" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <Visibility>Hidden</Visibility>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger SourceName="HyperlinkButtonDetails" RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CollapsedGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HyperlinkButtonDetails" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <Visibility>Hidden</Visibility>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HyperlinkButtonCollapsed" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Grid.Triggers>

        <Button Content="Свернуть" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="54,40,0,0" Name="HyperlinkButtonCollapsed" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <Button  Visibility="Hidden" Content="Подробности" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="54,40,0,0" Name="HyperlinkButtonDetails" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
        <Grid x:Name="CollapsedGrid" Margin="40,97,69,37" Visibility="Visible">
            <Border Grid.ColumnSpan='2' BorderThickness='1' BorderBrush='#FFD4D4D4' Padding='10,5'>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width='Auto'/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width='6'/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width='*'/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height='Auto'/>
                        <RowDefinition Height='5'/>
                        <RowDefinition Height='Auto'/>
                        <RowDefinition Height='5'/>
                        <RowDefinition Height='Auto'/>
                        <RowDefinition Height='*'/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text='gfgfgfgfgfgfgf:'/>
                    <StackPanel  Orientation='Horizontal' Grid.Column='2'>
                        <TextBlock Text='100000000000000000.00' Margin='0,0,6,0'/>
                        <TextBlock Text='eur'/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text='tttttttttttttt:'  Grid.Row='2'/>
                    <StackPanel  Orientation='Horizontal'  Grid.Row='2' Grid.Column='2'  >
                        <TextBlock Text='0'   Margin='0,0,6,0'/>
                        <TextBlock Text='eur'/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text='rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr:'  Grid.Row='4'/>
                    <StackPanel  Orientation='Horizontal'  Grid.Row='4' Grid.Column='2' >
                        <TextBlock Text='10000000'   Margin='0,0,6,0'/>
                        <TextBlock Text='eur'/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

На MSDN написано, что в Silverlight можно обрабатывать только событие Loaded [MSDN EventTrigger Silverlight](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb979699(v=vs.95).aspx)

> In Silverlight, the only event that you can use for an EventTrigger is
>   the Loaded event.

В связи с этим вопрос, возможно ли реализовать тоже самое на Silverlight, исключительно на XAML и если да, то как?